# rendering array on django template

Tags: python, django, templates, orm

I have following view

```
def deals(request):
    usr=UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    merchant=MerchantProfile.objects.get(user_id=usr.id)
    dealItems=MerchantDeal.objects.filter(merchant_id=merchant.id)
    stateText = {1 : 'Created',
                  2 : 'Activated',
                  3 : 'Completed'}

    return render_to_response('deals.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the model `MerchantDeal` i have one field state_id with three ids 1,2,3 for created, completed and used respectively

I have following template

```
<table>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Deals</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Start date </th>
                    <th>End date </th>
                    <th>Used</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                  </tr>
                  {% for Item in dealItems %}
                  <tr class="gray">
                    <td>{{Item.title|capfirst}} </td>
                    <td >{{Item.current_state}}</td>
                    <td>{{Item.start_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{Item.end_date}}</td>
                    <td width="90">{{Item.used}}</td>
                    <td width="92"><a class="ajax cboxElement" href="/ajax/item?id={{foodItem.id}}">edit</a></td>
                  </tr>
                  {%endfor%}
                </table>
```

This is show current_state as 1,2,3 instead of created,completed and used. I have defined stateText array too

```
stateText = {1 : 'Created',
             2 : 'Activated',
             3 : 'Completed'}
```

How to render that for 1,2,3 which comes from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MerchantDeal` model:

```
STATE_CHOICES = ((1,'Created'),(2,'Activated'),(3,'Completed'))

class MerchantDeal(models.Model):
    # .. your various other fields
    current_state = models.IntegerField(choices=STATE_CHOICES)
```

Then in your template:

```
<td>{{ Item.get_current_state.display }}</td>
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) details how this works.